# Fastest way to perform string lookups?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, optimization

Assuming we have a certain number of possible strings:

```
possible_strings_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

and receive new strings that are known to be one of them. We want to assign an integer to every new string, for example

```
if new_string == 'foo':
    return 0
elif new_string == 'bar':
    return 1
...
```

What is the fastest way to do that in Python 3.6?
I tried several ways and using a dictionary is the fastest so far:

```
list_index 2.7494255019701086
dictionary 0.9412809460191056
if_elif_else 2.10705983400112
lambda_function 2.6321219780365936
tupple_index 2.751029207953252
ternary 1.931659944995772
np_where 15.610908019007184
```

However I am more or less a Python newbie and I'm interested if there are other and faster solutions. Do you have any suggestions?

My complete testig code:

```
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np

def list_index(i):
    return(possible_strings_list.index(i))

def dictionary(i):
    return possible_strings_dict[i]

def tupple_index(i):
    return possible_strings_tup.index(i)


def if_elif_else(i):
    if i == 'foo':
        return 1
    elif i == 'bar':
        return 2
    elif i == 'baz':
        return 3
    elif i == 'qux':
        return 4
    elif i == 'spam':
        return 5
    elif i == 'ham':
        return 6
    elif i == 'eggs':
        return 7

def ternary(i):
    return 0 if i == 'foo' else 1 if i == 'baz' else 2 if i == 'bar' else 3 if i == 'qux' else 4 if i == 'spam'else 5 if i == 'ham' else 6

n = lambda i: 0 if i == 'foo' else 1 if i == 'baz' else 2 if i == 'bar' else 3 if i == 'qux' else 4 if i == 'spam'else 5 if i == 'ham' else 6
def lambda_function(i):
    return n(i)

def np_where(i):
    return np.where(possible_strings_array == i)[0][0]

##
def check(function):
    for i in testlist:
        function(i)

possible_strings_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
testlist = [random.choice(possible_strings_list) for i in range(1000)]
possible_strings_dict = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'baz':2, 'qux':3, 'spam':4, 'ham':5, 'eggs':6}
possible_strings_tup = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs')
allfunctions = [list_index, dictionary, if_elif_else, lambda_function, tupple_index, ternary, np_where]

for function in allfunctions:
    t = timeit.Timer(lambda: check(function))
    print(function.__name__, t.timeit(number=10000))
```

Comment: using a dictionary is indeed the fastest way as far as I know. I don't expect you'll find anything better as this is exactly the intended use of a dictionary.

Comment: Not really, a lookup dictionary is probably goning be your best option.

Comment: You could sort the list and try binary search from the `bisect` module, just for fun. But a dict is certainly the most Pythonic way.

Comment: Looks like you are already doing the performance testing. Note that you'll get different performance characteristics as the size of the list scales. Some methods will have constant time, some linear, and some exponential. Are you testing something specific, or just the general case?

Comment: You can construct the dict like this: `d = dict(zip(possible_strings_list,range(len(possible_strings_list))))`

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Thanks for the hint. I started that test for a project with only 10 different strings. Its currently paused but the problem stuck to my head. Maybe I'll test how the methods would perform on larger lists. I also thought that knowledge about the likelihood for each string occurring might have an impact. Does it make a performance difference to lookup the first element in a dict compared to the last (or the index in a list)

Comment: @elpunkt I'm not a real python guru but I expect that a dictionary has constant lookup, like a hashtable, but a list has linear lookup as each value needs to be inspected. So the list lookup cost would depend on where the item is (first is faster than last), and the dictionary doesn't.

Comment: Note, your `lambda_function` *returns a function*, not a the value you are looking for. But yeah, you aren't going to beat a `dict` for this use-case in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! This was actually the first time I used lambda in Python. Corrected it. This nearly doubled the time needed for the lambda lookup.

Comment: dict = hash table in python so the average time complexity will be O(1) and the worst is O(n).  It will be hard to beat for most use cases (unless you search on value)

Comment: Assuming a list of unique words, build a dictionary like this `{k:i for i, k in enumerate(lst)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary lookup is the fastest possible way to perform this search. In doing an analysis like this, you would normally compare the [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of each process.

For the dictionary lookup, the time complexity is "constant time", or O(1). While this can mean it is generally an integer value of steps that the algorithm can take, it is literally one in this instance.

The other methods will require iteration (or in the case of the if elses traversal - which is essentially a similar approach). These will range from needing to look at all values O(n), to needing to look at some values, O(log n).

As n is the size of the examining set, and as the set gets larger, the variance in the results will as well, with the dictionary consistently outperforming the other options shown.

There is no possible way to be faster than O(1). The only downside to the approach you have shown is that it may require more memory as the set grows, this is referred to as the Spacial Complexity of the algorithm. In this instance though, since we only need one value per item in the set, the spacial complexity will be O(n) which is negligible.

In a general sense of optimizations, it is important to consider how much complexity is present in a current solution, and how much sense it makes to improve on that complexity. If improvements are to be made, they should be aimed at getting to different tiers of performance, for example getting from O(n) to O(log n) or O(log n) to O(1).

[image: Time Complexity Comparisons]
<sub>Image courtesy: http://bigocheatsheet.com/</sub>

Micro-optimizations tend to be of the case where an optimization is made to and from the same complexity tier, and these are often not constructive in and of themselves.

Comment: I'd suggest that if the set of possible strings is fixed (which sounds like the case here) then the complexity of the algorithm doesn't matter.

Comment: @Jeff - The complexity has nothing to do with the size of the set, fixed or not. It is the amount of times an operation needs to happen in order to reach a solution. Given this situation of a set size of 7, and an O(n!) algorithm, that would be 5040 operations. Compare that with 1.

Comment: I over-generalized and meant Big-O complexity. Big-O notation is asymptotic behavior and ignores any lower order terms. The complexity of a O(1) algorithm and a O(n!) algorithm could really be 1000000 and n!, respectively, in which case the O(n!) would perform better for a size of 7.